# JHipster module fails to execute - function not found

Tags: javascript, jhipster

```
OS: Windows 10
Node.js: 8.16.2
npm: 6.4.1
JHipster: 6.4.1
```

I am learning about JHipster and JHipster modules and am doing a lot of reading and experimenting. I have almost no experience with Javascript or Node.js.

I have discovered the JHipster module generator (https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster-module) and used it to create a basic "Hello World" module.

I created a simple monolith JHipster application (no entities), which I ran to make sure works, and it does. I then attempted to run my module via `yo jhipster-helloworld`.

I get an error right off the bat:

```
> yo jhipster-helloworld
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: this.getJhipsterAppConfig is not a function
    at module.exports.readConfig (C:\Users\JO24447\workspace\jhipster\modules\mod3\generators\app\index.js:16:47)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\JO24447\workspace\jhipster\modules\mod3\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\index.js:424:27)
    at C:\Users\JO24447\workspace\jhipster\modules\mod3\node_modules\run-async\index.js:25:25
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\JO24447\workspace\jhipster\modules\mod3\node_modules\run-async\index.js:24:19
    at self.env.runLoop.add.completed (C:\Users\JO24447\workspace\jhipster\modules\mod3\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\index.js:425:13)
    at runCallback (timers.js:810:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:768:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:745:5)
```

The referenced function call is in my (generated) module code:

```
module.exports = class extends BaseGenerator {
...
            readConfig() {
                this.jhipsterAppConfig = this.getJhipsterAppConfig();
                if (!this.jhipsterAppConfig) {
                    this.error('Can\'t read .yo-rc.json');
                }
            },
...
        };
    }
```

Is this due to incompatible versions between what was generated by the module generator and the JHipster libraries available in my installed distribution?

I've run into similar issues of undefined functions in generated code elsewhere.

Comment: The current release of the module generator is out of date with JHipster v6 support (all work is done on people's personal time).  You can install the master version in order to generate a compatible module with `npm install -g https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster-module`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. How does installing the "master" version allow me to generate a compatible module? Why would it work, while the "current release" does not. So, once I've installed this, would I just use it normally, or do I need to do something special?

Comment: The last release of `generator-jhipster-module` was on 9/20, the commit fixing compatibility with JHipster v6 was on 9/28. No release has been made since then.  Yes, install and run normally with `yo jhipster-module`